# How to replace item in a listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, contextmenu

I have a `ListBox` which contains a `ContentMenu` like follows:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lb_Configuration" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="lb_Configuration_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct}" >
     <ListBox.ContextMenu>
          <ContextMenu>
               <MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="MenuItemDelete_Click"/>
               <MenuItem Header="Replace" Click="MenuItemReplace_Click"/>
               <MenuItem Header="Insert" Click="MenuItemInsert_Click"/>
          </ContextMenu>
     </ListBox.ContextMenu>                                                    
</ListBox>
```

When I want to `Delete` the item in the `ListBox`:

```
private void MenuItemDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Product itemToDelete = lb_Configuration.SelectedItem as Product;
     if (lb_Configuration.SelectedIndex < 0) return;
     else
     {
         lb_Configuration.Items.RemoveAt(lb_Configuration.SelectedIndex);
     }

}
```

Now the problem is I also want to replace the `SelectedItem` in the listbox, so I assuming that I also should popup a `ContextMenu` and binding the `ItemsSource` to it? How I suppose to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Replace the selected item with what?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just delete the old entry the same way you did it in the delete method. Then just use `Items.InsertAt(Int32, Object)` to insert an item into that same index.

For example,

```
private void MenuItemReplace_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Product replacementProduct = new Product();
     // Grab the old index
     int index = lb_Configuration.SelectedIndex;
     // Do any product setup configuration here 

     if (index < 0) return;
     else
     {
         // Remove, insert, and refresh the ListBox
         lb_Configuration.Items.RemoveAt(index);
         lb_Configuration.Items.InsertAt(index, replacementProduct); 
         lb_Configuration.RefreshItems();
     }
}
```

If you want more details look at [ListBox.Items.InsertAt()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.insert(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your replay. But what I want to know is how to get the Object of the `MenuItem`.